# save a series of dependent db objects in a database using scala and slick

Tags: scala, slick

I have a database where we use Scala and Slick to talk to the database. I have 4 scala classes Obj1, Obj2, Obj3 , Obj4 that need to be created one after the other as, for example, Obj2 could have a foreign key that points to Obj1, Obj3 has two foreign keys that point to Obj1 and Obj2, etc. So, as I understand each ObjK after Obj1 needs to wait for the previous ones to be in the database. 
How can this be addressed in Scala/Slick?
Thx

Comment: What did you try, and what happened?

Comment: I am still looking for some answer. But I found this: 
def insert(user: User) = db
  .run(users returning users.map(_.id) += user)
  .map(id => user.copy(id = Some(id)))

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I guess.

```
def ins(o1: Obj1, o2: Obj2, o3: Obj3): Future[(Obj1, Obj2, Obj3)] = {
  for {
    id1 <- db.run(obj1s returning obj1s.map(_.id) += o1)
    o1updated = o1.copy(id = id1)
    o2updated = o2.copy(o1id = id1)
    o2id <- db.run(obj2s ... += o2updated)
    ...
  } yield (o1updated, o2updated, ...)
}
```

You would get a better response if you provide some example code with real class definitions, function signatures, example input and output etc. I.e. what did you try, and what happened?